# Scrolling in Cypress when running on a VSTS Pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, cypress

This is a curious one....I've had to insert a `scrollTo` entry into my E2E Cypress test:

```
// More details for Standard Twin,     
            cy.scrollTo('0%,60%');
    cy.wait(3000);
    cy.get(':nth-child(2) > :nth-child(1) > :nth-child(1) > .jss639 > .jss675 > .jss963 > .jss959 > .jss985 > .jss578 > :nth-child(1) > .jss476 > .jss550').click();
```

Without the scrollTo, the command button in the third line is NEVER found...I also had to put in a `cy.wait` too.

This now runs 100% of the time when run LOCALLY either headed or headless, Chrome or Electron, VS Code or the Cypress runner.

But as soon as I try to run in a VSTS Pipeline, no matter which options I use, the test will NOT find this element. I've also tried using scrollTo with PX values rather than %ages, but that was even less reliable.

It's almost as if the VSTS pipeline is 'ignoring' the scroll instruction.

Anyone advise please?

Thanks
David

Comment: Thanks for your question, it led me to a solution to a flaky problem I had with an element scrolled out of view (occurs only when testing).

Answer (score 1):

if you have the following style in your application it might interfere with Cypress scrolling behaviour:

```
html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }
```

You can fix it with the following code in cypress:

```
cy.get('html').invoke('attr', 'style', 'scroll-behavior: inherit');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try `scrollTo()` command in a promise and see if that make any difference;

```
cy.window().then((win) => {
   win.scrollTo('0%','60%');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @soccerway. Tried this but received the following error: `TypeError: Failed to execute 'scrollTo' on 'Window': parameter 1 ('options') is not an object.`

Comment: @soccerway, seems you are using the native window `scrollTo`. Take a look at [Window.scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo), your parameter looks incorrect, should be either a pair of numbers or an object.

Comment: @DavidRedmayne, on the same note - [Cypress-scrollTo
-coordintates](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/scrollto.html#Coordinates) indicates your parameter is incorrect also - maybe `cy.scrollTo('0%', '60%')` instead of `cy.scrollTo('0%,60%')`. (Although why it works locally is a puzzle).

Answer (score 0):

Another option to try is

```js
cy.get(...).scrollIntoView()
cy.get(...).click()
```

I can't really test it since it is a bit of a fussy scenario to reproduce.

Docs [Cypress scrollIntoView()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/scrollintoview.html#Syntax)